# How do associations affect the way we create objects in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I understand that associations are important because this gives us a way of linking two objects together so they have a 'relation' and we can query through both of them. For example,

**A landing page belongs to a blog user** & **a blog user can have many landing pages**

We obviously go into the models and apply the correct methods 'has_many' and 'belongs_to'. We also create a migration and add the foreign key to the 'belongs_to' model. This being the 'landing page'.

**My problem:**

When creating a landing page, it is possible to choose a blog user. This obviously passes the blog user ID into the params. I want to save this ID into the foreign key field in the landing page model.

Is this possible **without** doing:

```
def create
    @landing_page = @blog_user.landing_pages.build(landing_pages_params)
end
```

Why do you have to go through a **blog user**? Another example:

```
def new
   @landing_page = @blog_user.landing_pages.new
end
```

What is the purpose of doing it this way? Surely passing the ID into the field is enough without going through the blog_user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you could do something like

```
@landing_page = LandingPages.new(blog_user_id: X)
```

Obviously, you need to know the ID of the `BlogUser` record. You'll then be able to access the newly associated `BlogUser` as you'd expect

```
@landing_page.blog_user #=> BlogUser(id: X)
```

Comment: In what scenario do people code in the way displayed above (in my question)

Comment: What is the difference? Could you expand your answer and give an example.